# Porque sale este error

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER VIEW Vsta_transformaciones
AS
SELECT * FROM Vsta_transformaciones
GO


select * from Vsta_transformaciones
```

Erro

> View or function 'Vsta_transformaciones' contains a self-reference.
>   Views or functions cannot reference themselves directly or indirectly

Comment: Y como soluciono el error

Comment: Qué es lo que quieres hacer? Normalmente dentro de una vista tienes que seleccionar determinados campos de una tabla para mostrarlos. Como te dijo @Guasy, en la definición de la vista estás llamando a la misma vista, por eso te da error.

Answer (score 1):

Tu vista esta haciendo un select de esa misma vista

```
ALTER VIEW Vsta_transformaciones
AS
SELECT * FROM mi_Tabla
GO


select * from Vsta_transformaciones
```

Debes de poner alguna consulta que no sea a tu misma vista

Comment: * Y como podria solucionarlo, es que ahora mismo realizo la consulta y sale error*

Comment: Dentro de la vista necesitas poner una consulta que no sea hacia tu misma vista